# Alternative to Storing ID List in SQL Database

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design

tl;dr: need to store arrays of ids of one table in a second table but all I can find are messy solutions.

I have the following database tables for a quiz system I'm designing (based on the top answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754350/mysql-database-design-for-a-quiz) question):

```
Quizzes
   -quiz_name TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL

Questions
   -id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
   -quiz_name TEXT REFERENCES Quizzes(quiz_name)
   -prompt TEXT NOT NULL
   -difficulty TEXT NOT NULL

Answers
   -id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
   -quiz_name TEXT REFERENCES Quizzes(quiz_name)
   -prompt TEXT NOT NULL
   -value INTEGER NOT NULL

Quiz_Results
   -id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
   -quiz_name TEXT REFERENCES Quizzes(quiz_name)
   -num_correct INTEGER NOT NULL
   -time TEXT NOT NULL
```

I want to have a table Question_Order that looks like this:

```
Question_Order
   -quiz_name TEXT REFERENCES Quizzes(quiz_name)
   -???some way of storing the IDs of all questions for this quiz
```

My first instinct was to just convert the IDs into a comma-separated string and shove it in Question_Order, but that seemed like a hacked-up solution that breaks good RDBMS practice.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444251/how-to-store-a-list-in-a-db-column) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549313/best-way-to-store-a-list-of-numbers-in-an-sql-database) one asked about storing a list of IDs.  But the point of having the questions in a separate table (instead of just chucking them all in the quizzes table) is that they can be reused, so I can't add an "order" column to questions.  I could also create a new table for each quiz (e.g. "First_Quiz_Order") but that's also pretty messy.
I'm using SQLite if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're hoping to re-use questions on different quizzes, you should not have the `quiz_name` field in the `questions` table.

You can solve that problem as well as the ordering problem by dropping `quiz_name` from `questions` and creating a table `quiz_question` *instead of* `question_order`:

```
 - quiz_name REFERENCES quizzes
 - question_id REFERENCES questions
 - question_order INT
```

This lets you share questions among quizzes and establish a (unique-per-quiz) order to the questions.

Comment: Definitely kudos for recognizing and avoiding the comma-separated string trap.